# Why am i getting an error: "buffsize musth be an integer" for mv shell command

Tags: python, shell

Why am i getting an error: "buffsize musth be an integer"

afer this line:

```
pid2 = subprocess.Popen(["mv"],glob.glob(os.path.basename(filename)+'[0-9]*'),folder);
```

It is a simply mv command with a blog shell expansion .

I want sth like `mv filename[0-9]* folder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's Python, so you don't need a semi-colon at the end of a line. Then, what you want is to supply one argument, i.e.

```
pid2 = subprocess.Popen(["mv"] +
                        glob.glob(os.path.basename(filename)+'[0-9]*') +
                        [folder])
```

Otherwise, you're specifying the result of `glob.glob` as the second argument (`bufsize`) of [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Also note that calling `mv` is unnecessary, Python already has the functionality to move files implemented in [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
for f in glob.glob(os.path.basename(filename)+'[0-9]*'):
    shutil.move(f, folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

As its first argument, `Popen()` takes either a string, or a list of arguments. You are just passing `["mv"]`; the `glob.glob(...)` and `folder` get interpreted as the second and the third arguments to [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which are `bufsize` and `executable`.

Try:

```
args = ["mv"] + [glob.glob(os.path.basename(filename)+'[0-9]*')] + [folder]
pid2 = subprocess.Popen(args)
```